# Difference between SP 2013 Preview development environment and SP 2013 Server Preview

Tags: development, 2013

Just going through few projects provided by Microsoft for sharepoint 2013 developers I seen requirements for development tools, it says

> > This sample requires the following:
>
> Visual Studio 2012  SharePoint development tools in Visual Studio 2012
>   A SharePoint 2013 Preview development environment

I installed sharepoint server 2013 but my laptop only has 4 GB ram so I couldn't test it much, how can I test developed sharepoint 2013 apps/solutions by me and if I can develop them without having sharepoint server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-code solution(infopath and SharePoint designer workflow) , you can use the office365 preview.

If you need to use Visual Studio then you need to have a development environment,you should upgrade your computer or looking for cloud solution like [CloudShare](http://www.cloudshare.com/)

Comment: +1 for cloudshare, I have it since 2 days ago, setup in 15 minutes, trial is for 15 days, after that is 49 dollars per month which is reasonable, I dont know if I will pay it because its not for company purposes, only because I want to learn a lot of sp 2013.